# How extract object by key/value from array using an other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

assuming we have two arrays like that :

```
var array1 = [
    {"name":"foo", "age": 13},
    {"name":"bar", "age": 15},
    {"name":"foobar", "age": 9},

    {"name":"i", "age": 60},
    {"name":"want", "age": 41},
    {"name":"to", "age": 31},
    {"name":"extract", "age": 2},
    {"name":"all", "age": 34},
    {"name":"these", "age": 54}
];

var array2 = [
    {"name":"foo", "age": 13},
    {"name":"bar", "age": 15},
    {"name":"foobar", "age": 9}
];
```

I would like to extract from `array1` all objects i have **not** in `array2` using the key `name` as reference. So at the end of the treatment, I would like to have the array :

```
var expectedResults = [
    {"name":"i", "age": 60},
    {"name":"want", "age": 41},
    {"name":"to", "age": 31},
    {"name":"extract", "age": 2},
    {"name":"all", "age": 34},
    {"name":"these", "age": 54}
}
```

Any idea to do that ? I can't find a method in JS which seems to allow that kind of filter.

Comment: Just loop through the initial array, and keep the ones you need.

Comment: I hoped there is more elegant solution =/

Comment: *" I can't find a method in JS which seems to allow that kind of filter."* You know... sometimes you actually need to write a little code.

Comment: @kl94: It's the simplest thing that could work. I suggest you don't try to do premature optimization, and just get it to work first. From your question I got the impression you hadn't even managed to get it to work yet.

Comment: @cookiemonster Agree, but in some others languages. You can do it easily

Comment: @KaarelNummert Yes I did, but looping through array let me a piece a code not very readable at the end. That's why I ask that on SO.

Comment: I think its a great question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all the names from `array2` like this

```
var names = array2.map(function(currentObject) {
    return currentObject.name;
});
```

And filter objects from `array1`, based on the gathered `names` like this

```
var result = array1.filter(function(currentObject) {
    return names.indexOf(currentObject.name) === -1;
});

console.log(result);
```

**Output**

```
[ { name: 'i', age: 60 },
  { name: 'want', age: 41 },
  { name: 'to', age: 31 },
  { name: 'extract', age: 2 },
  { name: 'all', age: 34 },
  { name: 'these', age: 54 } ]
```

As you want to make the code a little shorter, you can do something like this

```
var result = array1.filter(function(currentObject) {
    return array2.every(function(currentArray2Object) {
        return currentArray2Object.name !== currentObject.name;
    })
});
```

But if the arrays are big, then the efficient solution would be

```
var names = array2.reduce(function(result, currentObject) {
    result[currentObject.name] = currentObject.age;
    return result;
}, {});

var result = array1.filter(function(currentObject) {
    return !names.hasOwnProperty(currentObject.name);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it did the work done. But I really thought there was a better way to do kind of work. Thanks again.

Comment: @kl94 By better, you mean shorter or efficient?

Comment: I was looking for a shorter solution, but I think we just can't. Once again, thanks you.

Comment: @kl94 I just included an alternate version, please check.

Comment: I have, thanks a lot. I don't know why I deserved downvotes, doesn't matter. Thanks

Comment: Wow... that's way shorter than the solution I was working on. Very cool.

Comment: @BenjaminAnderson Thanks :-) I also included an efficient version, please check.